# Single frequency solutions to wave equation - Two forms? Whats the difference?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

I've seen these two forms from multiple sources for solutions to Maxwell's equations:
$$
\cos(kz - \omega t)
$$
and
$$
\cos(\omega t - \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})
$$

The first one shows a wave travelling in the positive $z$ direction. What does the second one show? 
What's the significance of having swapping the signs on the two terms? i.e .$$\cos(-kz + \omega t)$$

Comment: What is $\cos(-x)$ equal to?

Comment: Yes, missed that thanks. What about the main part of the question can you assist?

Comment: My comment should address your question about swapping the signs no? Or is it the $k \cdot r$ vs $kz$ that bothers you?

Comment: Yes unclear. Also, if time is increasing are k and z both increasing and positive?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351975/traveling-wave-equation-sinkx-wt-vs-sin-wt-kx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$k = \dfrac {2\pi}{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the wave.

> $\cos(kz - \omega t)$

is the equation of a (plane wave) travelling in the positive $z$ direction.
You can think of it as $\cos(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)$ where $\vec k= k \,\hat z$ and $\vec r= z \,\hat z$.

The direction of the k-vector gives the direction of travel of the wave or the opposite direction if the form of the equation is $\cos(kz + \omega t)$.

> $\cos(\omega t - \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})$

is the equation of a wave in three dimensions travelling in the k-vector direction with $\vec k \cdot \vec r = k_{\rm x} \, x + k_{\rm y} \, y + k_{\rm z} \, z$

This [two-dimensional plane wave visualisation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2k-SEdiihs) may help you understand what is going on.

> $\cos(kz - \omega t)$ and $\cos(-kz + \omega t)= \cos (-[kz - \omega t])$

describe the same wave travelling in the positive z-direction because $\cos(-kz + \omega t)= \cos (-[kz - \omega t]) = \cos(kz - \omega t)$